# Camel-bindy : How to escape double quotes when marshalling CSV?

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel

I am trying to escape double quotes inside a CSV field content. This is required because the double quote character is already used to enclose the fields. 
But I don't see how to do that (escaping) with Camel/Camel-bindy.

What I want to produce (note how double quotes inside field content are escaped by doubling them):

> "Some";"people";"Never ""finish""";"their"

What I'm actually producing (this won't parse as CSV):

> *"Some";"people";"Never "finish"";"their"*

So,

- **Is there any option that I can add to tell Camel to escape quotes inside (all) CSV fields values?**
- **Otherwise, is there an alternative solution that i could use to get the same result?**

So far, following is the state of what i did :
My Camel version is 2.15. 
I use a POJO which is later marshalled to CSV by bindy.

This is how the POJO looks like

```
@CsvRecord(separator = ";", crlf = "UNIX", generateHeaderColumns = true, quote = "\"", quoting = true)
public class MyCsvPOJO
{
    @DataField(pos = 1)
    private String prop1 = ""; 

    // Some other properties + getters + setters
}
```

This is the camel route code that produces the CSV file (using Camel Java DSL) :

```
from("myRouteId")
    .beanRef("myPojoProducerBean")
    .marshal()
    .bindy(BindyType.Csv, MyCsvPOJO.class)
    .convertBodyTo(String.class, "UTF-8")
    .to("/path/to/the/ouput-file.csv");
```

I considered using a custom crafted https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-csv/apidocs/org/apache/camel/dataformat/csv/CsvDataFormat.html that I could feed to `.marshal(myCustomCsvDataFormat)`, but then I can no longer chain a call to `bindy(...)` because of incompatible return types.

So, at this point I'm stuck and any hint will be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try with a newer Camel version - 2.15.0 is a bit old and is EOL.

Comment: @ClausIbsen
I have upgraded to Camel 2.17.3
Still, i did not find any change/novelty in the API that could help answer my issue.

More specifically :

-  I did not find any new option in `@CsvRecord` nor `@DataField`
-  I still can not do `.marshal(myCustomCsvDataFormat)` and then `.bindy(...)`

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Escaping quotes would typically be \" and not ""

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.19.0 was introduced `quotingEscaped` to `@CsvRecord`:

> Indicate if the values must be escaped when quoting

[Source (CAMEL-7519)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7519)

**UPDATE:**

I was able to get in output file your desired result (*"Some";"people";"Never ""finish""";"their"*) using [Camel CSV](http://camel.apache.org/csv.html):

```
from("myRouteId")
    .process(exchange -> {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, String> map = mapper.convertValue(new SimplePojo(), Map.class);
        exchange.getIn().setBody(map);
    })
    .marshal(new CsvDataFormat().setDelimiter(';').setQuoteMode(QuoteMode.ALL))
    .to("file:out/?fileName=ouput-file.csv");
```

Where `SimplePojo` content is:

```
private String name = "Some";
private String people = "people";
private String never = "Never \"finish\"";
private String finish = "their"
```